# json_agg() with pseudo row

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

```
CREATE TABLE content
(
    code          INTEGER NOT NULL
  , nameid        TEXT    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO content(code, nameid) VALUES
  ( 0, 'Support')
, ( 1, 'Adrenaline')
, ( 2, 'Aquapark')
;
```

Need select all content as JSON array-object named 'content' with pseudo row with code = '' and nameid = 'All'

What i did:
1) Simple select

```
SELECT 
   json_build_object('content', (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
    'code',   s.code::TEXT
  , 'nameid', s.nameid::TEXT
  ))
  FROM content s
  )
);
```

Result is

```
{
    "content": [{
            "code": "0",
            "nameid": "Support"
        },
        {
            "code": "1",
            "nameid": "Adrenaline"
        },
        {
            "code": "2",
            "nameid": "Aquapark"
        }
    ]
}
```

All fine, but how to add pseudo row?
2) Best i can did

```
SELECT  
  json_build_object('content', json_build_array(
    json_build_object(
      'code',   ''
    , 'nameid', 'All'::TEXT),    
    (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
      'code',   s.code::TEXT
    , 'nameid', s.nameid::TEXT
  ))
  FROM content s
  ))
);
```

Result is

```
{
    "content": [{
            "code": "",
            "nameid": "All"
        },
        [{
                "code": "0",
                "nameid": "Support"
            },
            {
                "code": "1",
                "nameid": "Adrenaline"
            },
            {
                "code": "2",
                "nameid": "Aquapark"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And we have array in array, as in sql as in json, but i can not understand how to combine json_agg with pseudo row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_json()` and `union all`:

```
select jsonb_build_object('content', json_agg(to_json))
from (
    select to_json(c)
    from (select '' as code, 'All' as nameid) c
    union all
    select to_json(c)
    from content c
    ) s
```

Output:

```
 {
    "content": [
        {
            "code": "",
            "nameid": "All"
        },
        {
            "code": 0,
            "nameid": "Support"
        },
        {
            "code": 1,
            "nameid": "Adrenaline"
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "nameid": "Aquapark"
        }
    ]
 }
```

The version with an alias in the derived table:

```
select jsonb_build_object('content', json_agg(codes))
from (
    select to_json(c) as codes
    from (select '' as code, 'All' as nameid) c
    union all
    select to_json(c)
    from content c
    ) s
```

Comment: Yes, thank u, it works. Can u please explain me syntax of `json_agg(to_json))`? I see here no table/col in upper select, i assume that this sentence `json_agg(to_json))` is same as `json_agg(to_json(s)))`, am i correct?

Comment: The derived table (subquery in FROM) returns one column with name `to_json`. We could use an alias for this, without the alias the column is named after the function. See the updated answer.